# How to open files within the same workspace emacs

Tags: emacs

Currently, whenever I open a new file with emacs (I work terminal only) it opens it within a new workspace. That can be quite annoying for me as initially when I start working, I open my project which has some init stuff (lsp-go) that takes a few minutes (monorepo). After that, I would like that whenever I open a new file (from the terminal again) that it uses the same workspace as prior so that it does not have to reinitialise everything (+ I would like to keep my buffers within the same workspace).

Here are some of my aliases:

```
alias estart="emacs --daemon"
alias estop='emacsclient -e "(kill-emacs)"'

alias e="emacsclient -nw"
```

My usual workflow is:

1. Start the server e.g. `estart`
2. Open the project `e .` (this will trigger lsp to load its stuff)
3. Later on, I open another file (could be anywhere even outside the project) `e someFile`

Note, I use doom emacs if that's of any use